# NestJS gRPC Middlware

Tags: nestjs, grpc

Does NestJS support middleware with gRPC? I'm following the example project [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/04-grpc) and then the middleware for logging the request entrypoint [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#applying-middleware).

In the example project it looks like there is an Express server along with the gRPC server. I'm using just a gRPC server.

```
const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(...);
await app.listenAsync();
```

So adding the following to the main app module:

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(LoggerMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

But nothing is logging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Middleware is exclusive to HTTP handlers. If you need middleware-like functionality, it would be better to use one of Nest's enhancers ([guards](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards), [interceptors](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors), [pipes](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes), or [filters](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters)). If you're looking to do some logging I'd suggest an intereptor as you have pre- and post- controller logic.

There's also my logging library [Ogma](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma) which has a Nest package and interceptor already which might be useful to look at